# FullCalendar "view" cacheable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, caching, fullcalendar

I am wondering if there is an option that i'm missing within FullCalendar.

I currently have the default view to be 'month'. But what I would like to happen is have it that IF the user views the "week" view, that the next time the user visits the website that the "week" view will show instead of the month. I am wondering about setting this out without using a DB.

I know jQuery UI Tabs has this ability using the 'cache' feature... is this something I can implement here as well? If so, how?

Any direction would be appreciative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

changeView doesn't work, as viewDisplay is called before it when the calendar is setup.

here's what works:

in the initializing object, add:

```
defaultView: $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView') || 'month',

viewDisplay: function(view) { $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView', view.name); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store this setting in a cookie using `jQuery.cookie` which is the library that the Tabs uses. How you handle this and where it is setup is more of a question that you need to answer, since you provided no code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use viewdisplay event

a good cookie plugin is http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie

Answer (score 0):

In your case you would have to put code in the the viewDisplay event.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewDisplay/

Something similar like this.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function(view) {
        setCookie("lastView", view.name);
    }
});
```

You can get more information on what inforamtion the **view** stores here
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/

**Then**,
 all you would have to do is use the the changeView when the page loads with a method (for example in the jQuery ready or something)

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/changeView/

something similar to

```
.fullCalendar( 'changeView', getCookie("lastView") )
```

There are many cookie plugins to jQuery but they all operate slightly different. I based my anser on some pureJS code found at http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html  there could be much better ones out ther somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this looks promising, I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

In version: 3.0.0 `viewDisplay` has been renamed to `viewRender`, so current code should like that:

`defaultView: $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView') || 'month',
viewRender: function(view) { $.cookie('fullcalendar_defaultView', view.name); }`